# How to use activerecord to exclude a value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given:

```
Group (id)
GroupMember (id, group_id)
```

Currently I can do:

```
@group.group_members
```

which returns all the group's members. I want to return all group_member except for the current_user. Is there a way to do something like

```
@group.group_members.where(:id not equal to current_user.id) ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close:

```
@group.group_members.where('id != ?', current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Today, you would use `.where.not` (that can also accept an array or a relation)...

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-not

```rb
@group.group_members.where.not(id: current_user)
```

or `.excluding` if you already have the model.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-excluding

```rb
@group.group_members.excluding(current_user)
```